# Unable to import json array to sql table in azure data factory

Tags: sql, json, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON array similar to this.

```
 {
"first":
    {
    "heading":{
    "row":[
    {
    "@captain" :"dhoni",
    "@runs":"50"
    },
    {
    "@captain" :"Kohli",
    "@runs":"150"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    }
```

But I am not sure how to add a sql script to import this JSON to my sql table. Can anyone help on this

Comment: Are you getting the above json as an output of another activity? And you want to insert `@captain and @runs` into your sql table. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham Yes I am getting this json as a lookup output response for my api

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham pls see my updated json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the rows extracted from the json returned by your API call with the help of `for each activity` and `script` activity.

- I have taken the given sample json as a parameter (Object type). First create a for each activity. The value of **items** in for each activity will be as follows:

```
@pipeline().parameters.my_json['first']['heading']['row']
```

- When we do this, for each iteration, the current item will be a row extracted from JSON that needs to be inserted into sql table.

[image]

- Now inside for each, create a script activity. Here, write a query to insert into the destination SQL table. You can use the following as your query

```
insert into dbo.player(captain,runs) values ('@{item()['@captain']}','@{item()['@runs']}')
```

[image]

**Another approach using stored procedure:**

- Create the following stored procedure in your database.

```
create  or  alter  procedure insert_player @json varchar(max)
as
begin
insert  into player SELECT  *  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.first.heading.row') with ([@captain] varchar(30),[@runs] varchar(30))
end
```

- Create a single stored procedure activity in data factory pipeline. Select the required linked service, the above created stored procedure and click **import** under *stored procedure parameter*.

```
@string(pipeline().parameters.my_json)
```

- **NOTE:** For me it is pipeline parameter, in your case it will be the lookup output that produced the above given sample JSON.

[image]

- When I debug the pipeline, it runs successfully and inserts the values into the respective table.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Saideep Arikontham  Thank you so much means a lot.But now I am getting another error in stored procedure script ;insert  into player SELECT  *  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.first.heading.row'); with ([@captain] varchar(30),[@runs] varchar(30))                                                                                                   Incorrect syntax near '('

Comment: Hey @BeingReal, there is an additional `;` in the query that you are trying to execute (before with). Please remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: if i remove that I am getting error like Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: What is your the type of your database? is it SQL server or MySQL?

Comment: Hi Im using sql server

Comment: What is your sink database type? is it Azure SQL database?

Comment: yes it is azure sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247680/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-being-real).